# Beam on Flink runner not able to advance watermarks on a high load

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

We are running a Beam application on Flink runner (Beam 2.29 and Flink 1.12) which reads from Kafka and writes to S3  once every 5 minutes. My window and s3 writes looks like

```
                            FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(5)))
                            .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
                            .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO, Window.ClosingBehavior.FIRE_ALWAYS)
                            .discardingFiredPanes())
                            .apply(FileIO.<GenericRecord>write()
                            .via(ParquetIO.sink(schema))
                            .to(outputPath)
                            .withNumShards(5)
                            .withNaming(new CustomFileNaming("snappy.parquet")));
```

Resources allocated: 5 task slots each with 3 CPU and 32 GB RAM. We are using RocksDB as state backend and giving 50% of memory to off-heap.

Its running fine with lighter loads. But when it gets heavier load from Kafka (7500 or more records per sec – each record around 7KB in size), we are seeing that no files are being written to S3.We are using AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow() which is trigerring only when the watermark reaches the end of window.

After debugging we found that watermarks are not being advanced during heavy loads and as a result event time triggers after watermark reaches end of window because of which s3 writes will happen are not getting triggered. So the data is accumulating in off-heap which results in out of memory after some time.

Any idea on why watermarks are not advancing under high load.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this with more machines? If the data is coming in faster than it can be processed, the watermark will fall more and more behind.

Comment: It works fine if we double up the resources but we are trying to figure out why beam need such heavy resources to process a 10k tps pipeline. We also tried using global window and processing time triggers. We have observed we get output in s3 with records which are more than the current watermarks from all the pods, still watermark shows an older timestamp which eventually results in OOM. We are investigating more on if issues is with How kafka is assigning watermarks to incoming records or something is happening on How flink is handling watermark wit s3 writes.

Comment: Highly appreciate if you have any inputs.

Comment: global window that we tried - `parquetRecord.apply("Batch Events", Window.<GenericRecord>into(new GlobalWindows())
                    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime
                                    .pastFirstElementInPane()
                                    .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(Integer.parseInt(windowTime))))).discardingFiredPanes()`

Comment: I would note that care needs to be taken using the GlobalWindow in streaming mode, as it never "finishes" and so can't be completely garbage collected (e.g. if there are keys that you never see again). You could also try using a profiler to see where your resources are being spent.